# Objeto FormData() para envio de arquivos via ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso enviar dados de um formulário via ajax para o servidor (php).
Eu utilizei o objeto FormData() mas sem sucesso. 
Parte do meu jquery:

```js
var formdata = new FormData($("#myform"));
var link = "form/insert";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: link,
            data: formdata ,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false

        }).done(function (data) {
            $("div.container-fluid").html(data);
        });
```

meu html tem:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" name="name">
 <input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" />
```

Ao executar o script só retorna null.
Teria como enviar via ajax o input texto e o file?

Comment: Seu link está com a url correta?

Comment: Está sim! Na minha aplicação eu reescrevo  o link. Eu recebo os dados perfeitamente no php (o problema é o envio do arquivo)

Comment: @BrunoNascimento sou dev c# mas vou tentar te ajudar hehehe', no c# eu faço da seguinte maneira. Olhe esse [**javascript**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/brbaeLjd/)

Comment: @Brunno seu código está ok. Testei aqui e tudo certo. Sendo que eu ainda não consigo fazer upload do formulário junto com o file. Estou jogando o envio do file para o Callback. Mas, não queria fazer desta forma. Teria alguma dica?

Comment: @BrunoNascimento tente fazer da seguinte [**forma**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/jvaLk6qh/) se der certo me avise que posto como resposta :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quando recuperar o form pode ser que retorne um vetor então pegue a chave 0 do mesmo (caso exista somente um).

> **Nota:** Verifique se o enctype do form esta com o valor "multipart/form-data"

```
//Exemplo do JS
var formdata = new FormData($("form[name='nome_do_form']")[0]);
var link = "form/insert";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: formdata ,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false

    }).done(function (data) {
        $("div.container-fluid").html(data);
    });
```

**Exemplo do HTML:**

```
<form name="nome_do_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" name="name">
     <input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Exemplo do PHP:**

```
<?php

echo "Texto: " . $_POST['name'] . '<br/><br/>';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], __DIR__."/upload_".date('YmdHis')."_".$_FILES['arquivo']['name'])) {
        echo "Arquivo recebido {$_FILES['arquivo']['name']} - o seu tamanho é de  {$_FILES['arquivo']['size']}";
} else {
        echo "Falha ao fazer upload!";
}
```

Comment: @HiagoSousa e após o usuário selecionar como pode ser enviado esses dados selecionado para o mysql . Fica o meu caso tem como vê http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181981/form-din%C3%A2mico-e-envio-para-o-mysql-via-jquery-e-ajax?noredirect=1#comment376494_181981

Comment: Excelente, valeu

Comment: Não estou conseguindo enviar FILE via AJAX, usei de acordo com esse exemplo e não funcionou.

Comment: @DeveloperWebSistem... qual o S.O. você esta utilizando? Verificou as permissões de escrita na pasta onde deseja fazer o upload?

Comment: @HiagoSouza olá amigo, já resolvi o problema obrigado pelo feedback.