# Envio de upload por ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu fiz o código em ajax para o envio de informações através do método click, porém o arquivo não chega no e-mail, somente os demais dados, no Console aparece o array com tipo do arquivo, tamanho, nome, tudo certinho porém não ta funcionando... Não sei como inserir o trecho php aqui, mas enviando o formulario diretamente pelo php funciona, então o erro só pode estar no tratamento do file do ajax

```js
$("#enviar").click(function() {
  var form_data = new FormData();
  var file_data = $("#image1").prop("files")[0];
  form_data.append("#image1", file_data);
  form_data.append("nome_completo", $("#nome_completo").val());

  var settings = {
    "url": "curriculo.php",
    "method": "POST",
    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "data": form_data
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="msform" method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>Nome Completo*</label>
    <input id="nome_completo" name="curriculo[nome_completo]" minlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo*">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="browse-wrap">
        <div class="title">Anexar Currículo</div>
        <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1" class="upload" title="Anexar Currículo">
      </div>
      <span class="upload-path"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Qual seria a diferença desta pergunta para esta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312012/enviar-input-file-por-ajax

Comment: O código está completamente modificado, mais fácil de identificar o problema nesse aqui, tentei apagar o anterior

Comment: Poderia editar o outro sem precisar duplicar a pergunta.

Comment: Porque o `contentType : false` ?

Comment: @MatheusReis quando eu tentei usar outro termo os dados não iam para o php, só ele no false comecei a receber certinho, menos o file

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94754/objeto-formdata-para-envio-de-arquivos-via-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Vou fazer o mesmo pedido da pergunta anterior que você fez e tem o mesmo problema. Você pode postar um exemplo completo e verificável? Com o código postado não dá para reproduzir o problema. Nem o elemento clicável tem no código da pergunta. Se quiser uma resposta evite dar trabalho a quem quer solucionar seu problema. Qualquer dúvida leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Código da pagina curriculo e send?

Comment: Consegui resolver, era um erro de digitação no código. Obrigado a todos!